# HABTM with additional columns for recipe ingredients

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

For my recipe-sharing website, I want to create a database and CakePHP models for the recipes and their ingredients.

I created two tables: recipes and ingredients. The third table is a HABTM table for ingredients_recipes, which also stores the amount of ingredients needed for the recipes. How do I create a model for the third table?

The third table would look something like this:

`recipe_id

ingredient_id

amount

measurement_unit`

I also thought of adding another table for measurement_units to store all possible units (ex. tablespoon, tea spoon, cup, etc.). Would that be too much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HABTM, within Cake's ORM, is actually an abstraction of the following two model association structures (using your example):

```
Recipe
-> hasMany IngredientsRecipe
           -> belongsTo Ingredient
```

and

```
Ingredient
-> hasMany IngredientsRecipe
           -> belongsTo Recipe
```

The `IngredientsRecipe` model is inferred, and used only to link the two first-class models, `Ingredient` and `Recipe`.

However, in your case, you actually *want* `IngredientsRecipe` to be a first-class model, which breaks the HABTM abstraction. In fact, what you need to do is explicitly define the two association structures above, so that Cake treats the `IngredientsRecipe` model as a first-class citizen, allowing you to query against it, save records to it, etc.

Also, no, I don't think it's too much to create an additional `MeasurementUnit` model. It will provide you much more flexibility down the line.

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I am completely lost in all this. How do I explicitly define the two association structures? By creating the model php file, just like the files for ingredients and recipes?

Comment: Sorry to be so long getting back to you. Basically, you need to define three models instead of two, because you're not really joining `Recipe` and `Ingredient` directly together. Rather, you're joining `Recipe` to `RecipeElement` to `Ingredient`; and `Ingredient` to `RecipeElement` to `Recipe`. `Ingredient` and `Recipe` continue to fill the same role they do now, and `RecipeElement` comprises information about the specific measurements and units for each ingredient in a recipe. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: By way of explanation I have added an answer, but I doff my hat to Daniel ;)

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this then treat it one chunk at a time:

```
`Recipe` (1)--(n) IngredientsRecipe (n)--(1) Ingredient
```

1. In `Recipe`, create the association to `IngredientsRecipe`
2. In `Ingredient`,  create the association to `IngredientsRecipe`
3. In `IngredientsRecipe` create the association to `Recipe`
4. Still in `IngredientsRecipe` create the association to `Ingredient`

While you're doing it, forget about HABTM and think instead about `hasMany` and `belongsTo`

Incidentally, you are not bound to call the model IngredientsRecipe, that is just the default/convention.

When you're done, treat it like hasMany, belongsTo or HABTM as appropriate.