# Finding records via conditions in HABTM

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to find posts within a category that are associated with a category. Right now, I have this:

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Category->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.uri' => $uri))));
```

But this doesn't seem to work. An error is showing this:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Category.uri' in 'where clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

..<snipped>...

Query: SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`uri`, `Post`.`body`, `Post`.`created`, `Post`.`modified` FROM `posts` AS `Post` WHERE `Category`.`uri` = 'holidays'.
```

I've read that when you have HABTM between models, you should be able to retrieve it like so. However, the SQL shown doesn't JOIN the categories table.

```
// Category Model
class Category extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Category';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post'
        )
    );
}

// Post Model
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the more efficient code:

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Category->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.uri' => $uri
        ),
        'contain' => array('Post')
    )
));
```

Answer (score 4):

> I've read that when you have HABTM
>   between models, you should be able to
>   retrieve it like so.

I don't know where you read this, but your source is wrong. [Cake's documentation of HABTM associations](http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) deals with a scenario almost identical to yours, and the steps necessary to achieve the results you're after.

[My answer to another question about HABTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032313/habtm-with-additional-columns-for-recipe-ingredients/4033752#4033752) may be informative for understanding how Cake's ORM works under the covers.

Comment: Nice info about the internals of the CakePHP ORM, but can't see how that helps.

Comment: It helps by explaining why you can't constrain a query for Posts by a property of Categories -- because, under the hood, Cake never performs a `JOIN` on the `categories` and `posts` tables. It was an attempt at "teaching fishing" rather than "giving a fish." :-)

Comment: Well, I got that after reading a blog post by teknoid about HABTM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this worked. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'categories_posts',
        'alias' => 'CategoriesPosts',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.id = CategoriesPosts.category_id'
        )
    ),
    array('table' => 'posts',
        'alias' => 'Post',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'CategoriesPosts.post_id = Post.id',
        )
    )
);
$options['conditions'] = array(
    'Category.uri' => $uri
);
$options['fields'] = array(
    'DISTINCT(Category.uri), Post.*, Category.*'
);
$this->set('posts', $this->Category->find('all', $options));
```

Comment: There's nothing spectacularly wrong with solving your problem this way. The only caution I'd give is that you're breaking Cake's ORM abstraction some. You can achieve this same effect with `Model::bindModel` that don't require your Models know all about your how your Datasources work.

Comment: it is certanly not the easiest way