# How do I Find Categories within in Contained Model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I had a recent question here regarding [Finding records via conditions in habtm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268300/finding-records-via-conditions-in-habtm). Now, I could search for posts within a category I searched for.

Now, my questions is how to I retrieve the categories of each post. Sometimes a post has one or more categories in this query:

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Category->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.uri' => $uri
        ),
        'contain' => array('Post')
    )
));
```

I'd imagine something like this:

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Category->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.uri' => $uri
        ),
        'contain' => array('Post' => array(
            'contain' => 'Category'
        ))
    )
));
```

Here's what my models look like.

```
// Category Model
class Category extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Category';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post'
        )
    );
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}

// Post Model
    class Post extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'Post';
        var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Category' => array(
                'className' => 'Category'
            )
        );
        var $actsAs = array('Containable');
        var $virtualFields = array(
            'date_posted' => 'DATE_SUB(Post.created, INTERVAL 7 DAY)'
        );
    }
```

A sample data would be like this:

```
categories
id name
1  holidays
2  destinations

posts
id title
1  I am a post
2  I am another post

categories_posts
post_id category_id
1       1
2       2
2       1
```

I am retrieving posts from holidays.

```
Array
(
    [Category] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => holidays
            [uri] => holidays
            [created] => 2010-11-25 20:43:03
            [modified] => 2010-11-25 20:43:03
        )

    [Post] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => I am a post
                ),
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => I am a another post
                )
        )
)
```

The problem is that 1 of the posts are in two categories. I'd like to have that information also available.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to return only those Posts which have 2 or more Categories associated with them? Or, do you want to return Categories which have 2 or more Posts?

Comment: I want to return the Posts that are within a Category. I also want each Post to give information about their Categories(could be one or two).

Comment: If this isn't possible, is there some way to do it? In CodeIgniter, I would be looping through a model method from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaving my other answer as-is because it contains a lot of good info for those who may stumble upon it.  As far as solving your problem more elegantly?  You'll need to flip the find on it's head and search from the Post model with an ad-hoc join, like this:

```
// From the CategoriesController
$this->Category->Post->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'categories_posts',
            'alias' => 'CategoryFilter',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'CategoryFilter.post_id = Post.id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'categories',
            'alias' => 'CategoryUriFilter',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'CategoryUriFilter.id = CategoryFilter.category_id'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'CategoryUriFilter.uri' => $uri
    ),
    'contain' => array('Category')
));
```

The array returned will be formatted a bit differently, but it should contain all of the data you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Close.  Try this:

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Category->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.uri' => $uri
        ),
        'contain' => array('Post' => array('Category'))
    )
));
```

### Tangent

Writing Controller code like this has problems:

1. It will bloat your controller methods and make your controllers less readable.
2. It prevents you from re-using business logic among your different controllers.

You can satisfactorily correct these problems by moving your find call to a model method:

```
// Categories Controller
$this->set('posts', $this->Category->get_posts_with_cats($uri));

// Category Model
function get_posts_with_cats($uri) {
    $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Category.uri' => $uri),
        'contain' => array('Post' => array('Category'))
    ));
}
```

This makes your code **More Awesome**:

1. The controller is nice and [Skinny](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model), and super readable.
2. Now you can call the same method from any associated model.  So, for instance, in your `PostsController` you could call:    `$this->Post->Category->get_posts_with_cats($uri);`.  Your code is now [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

### Tangent #2

After you learn how to nest containable models like I've shown you, you may be tempted in the future to do something like this:

```
$this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Category.uri' => $uri),
        'contain' => array(
            'Post' => array(
                'Category' => array(
                    'Tag' => array('Author')
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

**The good news?**  You will get the desired model data from the above method (as long as you've defined all of these relationships).

**The terrible news?**  CakePHP doesn't know how to optimize the queries for deep associations like this.  So, as your database grows, you'll end up with dozens (if not hundreds (if not thousands)) of `SELECT` queries to the database, effectively bringing your application to a crawl (if not a *halt*.)

The good folk that design CakePHP are working on a better containable behavior for CakePHP 2.0, but you'll have to wait until then to get this level of precision.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does work.  The way I've nested the array in the containable parameter is correct.  If it's not working, check your relationship declarations.  You probably defined `$hasAndBelongsToMany` in the `Category` model, but not in the `Post` model.

Comment: actually it does the same queries even without the new containable parameter.

Comment: I've added more information. It seems that this approach is logical but it doesn't do anything. I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Ah.  Have you forgotten to add `Containable` to the list of components? http://book.cakephp.org/view/995/Configuring-Components

Comment: erg...  maybe not.  Let me analyze your new info.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this to get what I want:

```
function getPostsFromCategory($uri) {
        return $this->populatePosts($this->find(
            'first',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Category.uri' => $uri
                ),
                'contain' => array('Post' => array('Category'))
            )
        ));
    }

    function populatePosts($categoryPosts) {
        $posts = $categoryPosts['Post'];
        $count = count($categoryPosts['Post']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $categories = $this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Post.id' => $categoryPosts['Post'][$i]['id']),
            'contains' => array('Category')));

            // unset($categories['Post']);
            foreach ($categories['Category'] as $cat) {
                $categoryPosts['Post'][$i]['Categories'][] = $cat;
            }
            unset($categories);
        }
        return $categoryPosts;
    }
```

I really don't know if this can be done in a more CakePHP-y way though:

I returns something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Category] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => festivals
            [uri] => festivals
            [created] => 2010-11-25 20:43:03
            [modified] => 2010-11-25 20:43:03
        )

    [Post] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [title] => A Post
                    [Categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [name] => festivals
                                    [uri] => festivals
                                    [created] => 2010-11-25 20:43:03
                                    [modified] => 2010-11-25 20:43:03
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [name] => destinations
                                    [uri] => destinations
                                    [created] => 2010-11-28 13:04:52
                                    [modified] => 2010-11-28 13:04:52
                                )

                        )

                )
)
```